# How to handle methods and arguments retrieved from queue in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, queue

I have tkinter gui method used to pluck methods with or without argument stored in a queue.  The methods with or without arguments are put into the queue as a tuple.  The methods are those used to communicate with an i2c device (slow), hence the reason I'm going through this effort.

```
def process_queue(self):
        #print('Number of threads:', threading.active_count())
        #print(threading.current_thread().name)
        try:
            queued_method = self._queue.get(block=False)
            method = queued_method[0]
            print('Method name: ', method.__name__)
            if len(queued_method) == 1: # it was passed in with no arguments
                t = threading.Thread(target=method)
            if len(queued_method) > 1: # it was passed in with arguments
                args = queued_method[1:]
                #print('Method arguments: ', args)
                t = threading.Thread(target=method, args=args)
            t.start()
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
        root.after(100, self.process_queue)
```

My question is, is there a better way to do this aside from the way I'm doing it? ...and avoid the if len() stuff altogether?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at both posts, it might improve the approach to separate button invoked methods from the device polling function (it's not obvious from the code whether you've done this already). It might have the added benefit of removing the argument(s) handling dilemma. In answer to your question in the other post regarding calling a class method, it is a best practice to do so, especially with a GUI involved. And here is a basic answer how to do that.

```
from tkinter import *

class Panel(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        # Create some buttons that invoke the class methods.
        buttonA = Button(self, text="Print A", width=20, command=self.printA)
        buttonA.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news", padx=4, pady=4)

        # The following buttons use lambda functions because arguments are being passed.
        buttonOneArg = Button(self, text="One Argument", width=20,
            command=lambda a="Single Argument": self.oneArgMethod(a))
        buttonOneArg.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="news", padx=4, pady=4)

        buttonTwoArgs = Button(self, text="Two Arguments", width=20,
            command=lambda a="First argument", b="2nd arg": self.multiArgMethod(a,b))
        buttonTwoArgs.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="news", padx=4, pady=4)

        button3Args = Button(self, text="Three Arguments", width=20,
            command=lambda a="Arg 1", b="Arg 2", c="Arg 3": self.multiArgMethod(a,b,c))
        button3Args.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="news", padx=4, pady=4)

    def printA(self):
        print("A")

    def oneArgMethod(self, arg1):
        print("One argument:", arg1)

    def multiArgMethod(self, *args):
        for index,arg in enumerate(args):
            print("multiArgMethod argument", index, "=", arg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    # Create the panel by instantiating the class.
    app = Panel(root)
    app.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ron, I've sort of already implemented what you've mentioned...lambda is an amazing tool.  However, given the post here, am I handling the queue the right way?  Or are you suggesting I put lambda function/arguments in the queue?

Comment: I suggest that the queue be used for the cyclical polling work and that event methods on the class (called by the lambdas) be used for button press events. The `root.after()` command uses the same event loop that the button events do. The difference is that the `after` command *schedules* an event, whereas the lambda executes immediately. It is a good practice to separate user events from polling routines for debugging and easier code management.